# Convert to primitive

Tags: javascript, function, types

```js
console.log(sum(1)(2)(3));  // -> 6
console.log(sum(3)(15));   // -> 18 

function sum(a) {
  let currentSum = a;

  function f(b) {
    currentSum += b;
    return f;
  }
  f.toString = function() {
    return currentSum;
  };
  return f;
}
```

This function adds the arguments that are passed to it, and after all additions the string currentSum is returned. I don’t really understand how the conversion to a primitive occurs and why write it through a function

Comment: look's like a closure. don't you add some code on how to use this?

Comment: sum(1)(2)(3) // return 6.           
 If I understand correctly what you want

Comment: `sum(1)(2)(3)` doesn't return `6`. It returns a function object, which when used in e.g. `console.log` may automatically convert to string via `toString`. So `console.log(sum(1)(2)(3))` may print 6.

Comment: so, this is a closure with a "chaining" method...

Comment: Yes, That's exactly what I wanted to say. I don't understand the entry f.toString = function... Why we use it?

Comment: because [`.toString()`  is a default method to any JS Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString). This closure  overloading this method. So `console.log()` use this `.tostring()` method to display information

Comment: So we access f, return currentSum through the function and convert it to a string?

Comment: No f always return itself  (a function), you sould familiarize yourself with closures -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: thanks.I'm not very attentive...
it turns out that if we do not implement f.toString, then our sum function will always return the function f, while storing currSum =6 in its local environment (for the case of sum(1)(2)(3)). When using ``console.log,alert() and ==`` will there be a type conversion and sum will return currSum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `toString` function of a Function will return the *stringified function*. In other words: the primitive value of a Function is ... the function at hand. To display the (intermediate, [enclosed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)) `currentSum` primitive value from `f`, you need to override the `toString` function of `f`.

Maybe the next snippet clarifies this.

**Note**: the last `console.log` in the first snippet converts the result using `+sum(1)(2)(3)`. Why does it work? This is explained in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf):

> Unary plus performs number coercion on its operand, which, for most objects without @@toPrimitive, means calling its valueOf(). However, if the object doesn't have a custom valueOf() method, the base implementation will cause valueOf() to be ignored and the return value of toString() to be used instead.

```js
// note: default values for parameters added
function sum(startValue = 0) {
  // [currentSum] is enclosed for further operations
  let currentSum = startValue;
  
  function f(value = 0) {
    currentSum += value;
    // returning the function
    // makes it possible to call
    // it again with a new value
    return f;
  }
  
  // f.toString would deliver the stringification
  // of the function f. To retrieve the value of 
  // [currentSum] that should be overridden.
  f.toString = function() {
    return currentSum;
  };
  
  // return the function with the overridden
  // toString method
  return f;
}

function someFunction() {
  return `Hi! I am the result of someFunction()`;
}

// the primitive value of [someFunction] is ...
// a function, so you can call it using 
// its valueOf
console.log(`someFunction.valueOf()(): ${someFunction.valueOf()()}`);

// a functions default 'toString' returns
// the string representation of the function
console.log(`someFunction.toString(): ${someFunction.toString()}`);


const six = sum(1)(2)(3);
// six is a function
console.log(`const six = sum(1)(2)(3);
typeof six: ${typeof six}`);

// toString (of the function) is automatically 
// invoked within a template string
console.log(`current value of six: ${six}`);

// change [currentSum] (six is still a function)
console.log(`typeof six(10): ${typeof six(10)}`);

// the value of six has changed
console.log(`current value of six: ${six}`);

// comparisons with a Number
// no type coercion (==)
console.log(`six == 16 ${six == 16}`);

// use toString for type coerced comparison with Number
console.log(`six.toString() === 16 ${six.toString() === 16}`);

// [six] is still a function, so
console.log(`six === 16 ${six === 16}`);

// to compare a [sum] result with a number 
// with type coercion (===)
// it can be converted to Number (+)
// see answer text for explanation.
console.log(`+sum(1)(2)(3) === 6 ${+sum(1)(2)(3) === 6}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

For fun: because a `Function` is [just another `Object`](https://www.i-programmer.info/programming/113-javascript/16738-javascript-jems-functions-are-objects.html), you can also extend it with your own 'value' method. In that case you have to explicitly call the extension method(s) to retrieve the enclosed value.

```js
function sum(a = 0) {
  let currentSum = a;

  const f = (value = 0) => {
    currentSum += value;
    return f;
  }
  
  // extend
  f.value = _ => currentSum;
  f.reset = _ => { currentSum = 0; return f; }
  f.increment = _ => { currentSum += 1; return f; }
    
  return f;
}

const six = sum()(1)(2)(3);
console.log(`six.value(): ${six.value()}`);
console.log(`six(10).value(): ${six(10).value()}`);
console.log(`six.increment().value(): ${six.increment().value()}`);
console.log(`six.reset().value(): ${six.reset().value()}`);
console.log(`six(1)(2)(3).value(): ${six.reset()(1)(2)(3).value()}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

One step further may be to convert the methods to getters (so you don't need parentheses using them), or add your own setters to the function:

```js
function sum(a = 0) {
  let currentSum = a;

  function f(value = 0){
    currentSum += value;
    return f;
  }
  
  const extensions = {
    get value() { return currentSum; },
    set value(val) {currentSum = val; return f; },
    get reset() { currentSum = 0; return f; },
    get increment() { currentSum += 1; return f; },
  };
  
  Object.entries(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(extensions))
    .forEach( ([key, descriptor]) => { 
      Object.defineProperty(f, key, descriptor); 
    } );
  
  return f;
}

const six = sum(1)(2)(3);
console.log(`native six.toString(): ${six}`);
console.log(`six.value: ${six.value}`);
console.log(`six(10).value: ${six(10).value}`);
console.log(`six.increment.value: ${six.increment.value}`);
console.log(`six.reset.value: ${six.reset.value}`);
console.log(`six.increment(2)(3).value: ${six.increment(2)(3).value}`);
six.value = 12;
console.log(`six.value = 12;
six(30).value: ${six(30).value}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Did I understand correctly? We have the first argument a written to the variable currentSum and sum returns the function f, but does not call it, it turns out that if we pass the second argument b(2), then through closures we get the value of currentSum and add it with 2, again return f for the next arguments , if there are none, then we exit the function and to output the result we convert currentSum to the primitive f,we use the toString method, and we pass there that we need to convert currentSum to a string and when using == or alert further, will the string value currentSum be returned?

Comment: Not completely. The `sum` function can be called a [factory function](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-factory-functions/) returning a *modified function*  to add values to an enclosed value (the parameter value of the first call to `sum`). If you call the function without arguments, it will still return the function. Only when implicitly or explicitly `toString` is used, it will return the primitive value (as per the overridden `Function.toString` within the `sum` function.
I added extra comment and value comparisons to the first snippet that hopefully make things more clear

Answer (score 1):

**Q&R**:
-1- what is `sum()` ?
in JS everything is an Object (even if they are defined as a function).

-2- what is `currentSum` ?
it is a local value inside `sum()`.
this local value can only be changed inside the scope of `sum()`.

-3- what is `f` ?
an object function which add his argument value to `currentSum`
and return itself (a function)

-4- what is `f.toString` ?
it is an overloading method on the `f` object
it overload the deault `Object.prototype.toString()` (javascript is a prototype object model)

-5- what happend in `console.log(sum(1)(2)(3));` ?
there is differents step :

__a) `let fctA = sum(1)`  -> currentSum = 1,  and `return f` see sum()'s last line
__b) `let fctB = fctA(2)` -> currentSum += 2  and `return f`
__c) `let fctC = fctA(3)` -> currentSum += 3  and `return f`
__d) `let D = fctC.toString()` => call the `toString()` method of `f`.

```js
let fctA = sum(1);
let fctB = fctA(2);
let fctC = fctA(3);
let D = fctC.toString(); //--> sum is: 6

console.log( D );

function sum(a)
  {
  let currentSum = a;
  function f(b) 
    {
    currentSum += b;
    return f;
    }
  f.toString = function()
    {
    return `sum is: ${currentSum}`;
    };
  return f;
  }
```

> But how do we get into `f.toString` [?] because after the last argument we have return `f`

Yes it still return `f`.
But `f` is also a JS Object, which [as such] has a [default] method named `toString`.
As this method already exists for all JS objects, `f.toString` overrides this method by default.

--

There are at least 2 ways to write a js function:
(1) `function foo() {...}`
(2) `var foo = function() {...}`

in this code `f.toString = function()  {...}` this is way (2).
but `f.toString` also mean -> `toString` is a method on the Object `f`.

--

Maybe this could helps

```
console.log( sum(1)(2)(3) );
         ║    ┗┳━┛  ┃  ┃
         ║   A ▉────┃──┃──let currentSum = 1;
         ║     ┃    ┃  ┃    return f;
         ║     ┗━┳━━┛  ┃    
         ║     B ▉─────┃──currentSum += 2;
         ║       ┃     ┃    return f;    
         ║       ┗━━┳━━┛  
         ║        C ▉─────currentSum += 3;
         ║          ║         return f;
         ║          ║ 
        D╙──────────╨call prototype method of function.toString()
                       find overiding method: f.toString()
                            return `sum is: ${currentSum}`;
```

Comment: 1.It turns out that we have created a sum function and a local variable currSum, it stores the first argument a
2.Next, the function f and its local environment are initialized
3.Then our sum function returns f and the addition currSum and b occurs. Now the function f returns itself
4.This was clear to me before. But how do we get into f.toString because after the last argument we have return f?

Comment: I got it!! I didn’t quite understand the way to write a function without ()

Comment: Did I understand correctly? We have the first argument a written to the variable currentSum and sum returns the function f, but does not call it, it turns out that if we pass the second argument b(2), then through closures we get the value of currentSum and add it with 2, again return f for the next arguments , if there are none, then we exit the function and to output the result we convert currentSum to the primitive f,we use the toString method, and we pass there that we need to convert currentSum to a string and when using == or alert further, will the string value currentSum be returned?

Comment: @jeweler23jeweler23 when you write: `a=b*c*d*e`, this can be decomposed into steps: `M1=b*c`, `M2=M1*d`, `a=M2*d`. but it's still easier to write `a=b*c*d*e`.
it's the same case with sum(1)(2)(3).

Comment: @jeweler23jeweler23  You seem to neglect the fact that Javascript is an Object-based language. That is to say that the creation of a function is a creation of an Object, which is build from a  reference prototype, made with several methods, like the `toString` method.

Comment: @jeweler23jeweler23 added an explanation schema...

Comment: @jeweler23jeweler23 Otherwise, overall you understood correctly. Just FYI, in the original code with `return currentSum;` returns a numeric value, not a string...